# Wrapping a .dll or .dylib to Add an Error Check

Tags: c++, c, windows, macos, dynamic-linking

C++/C | macOS/Windows

I'm working cross platform & I have a "protected" dynamic library "**protected.dll**" that may not load sometimes (eg valid license isn't available, etc..). I want to add an error window that will popup if the host fails to load this dll. I also would like to not have to edit the source code of **protected.dll**. The host app & the dll interface are defined/implemented by a 3rd party.

My question is, can I make a simple "wrapper" dll that attempts to load **protected.dll** and then catches the error if it fails to do so? Would it be possible for this **wrapper.dll** to not know about any of the internal source code of **protected.dll** (ie not have to use any of its the header files). How would the symbols of **protected.dll** get forwarded to the main host process? Is there a "default" entry point that is always called within a dll, something similar to a *main()* in a regular executable?

Many thanks!!

Comment: For Windows, the entry point is `DllMain()`.  Don't know about the other OSes

Comment: Mac ones can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryDesignGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002013-SW17)